# Matplotlib imshow() gives an horizontal flipped density plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm interesting in plot a mixture of bivariate normal.

```
def func(x):
    cat = tfd.Categorical(probs=np.array([.5, .5],dtype=NP_DTYPE))
    comps = [tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=np.array([-5.0, -5.0],dtype=NP_DTYPE), scale_diag=tf.ones(2,dtype=DTYPE)*.1),
         tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=np.array([5.0, 5.0],dtype=NP_DTYPE), scale_diag=tf.ones(2,dtype=DTYPE)*.1)]

    mix = tfd.Mixture(cat=cat, components=comps)
    return mix.prob(x)
```

This is mixture of two bivariate normal. One centre at [5,5], another centre at [-5,-5]; both has diagonal covariance matrix with 0.1 along the diagonal. Each with the same mixing weight.

My code for plotting is this

```
# make these smaller to increase the resolution
dx, dy = 0.1, 0.1

x = np.arange(-10.0, 10.0, dx)
y = np.arange(-10.0, 10.0, dy)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.concatenate((X.reshape(-1,1),Y.reshape(-1,1)),axis=1)


extent = np.min(x), np.max(x), np.min(y), np.max(y)
fig = plt.figure(frameon=True)



Z2 = tf.log(func(Z) + 1e-6)
Z2 = sess.run(Z2)
Z2 = Z2.reshape(int(np.sqrt(Z2.shape[0])),int(np.sqrt(Z2.shape[0])))

im2 = plt.imshow(Z2, cmap=plt.cm.viridis, alpha=.9, interpolation='bilinear',
                 extent=extent)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The reason I flatten the mesh grid because I want to implement a generic density plotting such that it can plot any complicated 2D distributions. (an arbitrary 2D distribution that takes input with shape [N,D]; N is number of points and D is the dimension of each point)

However, this gives a weird plot

[image]

which horizontally flipped the plot as the high temperature region should be around [5,5] and [-5,-5]

Any help one fixing this ? (Because the imshow() is kind of blackbox and I need density function take a particular form of input; I couldn't figure out how to fix this problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `origin="lower"` to the arguments of your imshow plot.

The default value is `"upper"`, which makes sense for plotting images as they normally start in the top-left corner. For matrix-base plotting however, you'll usually want `origin="lower"`, otherwise your plot is flipped.

```
im2 = plt.imshow(Z2, cmap=plt.cm.viridis, alpha=.9, interpolation='bilinear',
                 extent=extent,origin='lower')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]